# Show that $\frac{1}{\vert G\vert}\sum_{g\in G}\phi_{t}v\in V^{G}$ for $v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

This exercise comes from Steinberg's *Representation Theory of Finite Groups*.
Let $\phi :G\rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation of a finite group $G$. Define the *fixed subspace*
$$V^{G}=\{ v\in V\,\vert\,\phi_{g}v=v,\forall g\in G\}$$
Show that
$$\frac{1}{\vert G\vert}\sum_{g\in G}\phi_{t}v\in V^{G}$$
for all $v\in V$.

I understand that if $v\in V^{G}$ we have $\phi_{g}v=v$ for $g\in G$. Then it follows that $$\frac{1}{\vert G\vert}\sum_{g\in G}\phi_{t}v=\frac{1}{\vert G\vert}\sum_{g\in G}v = \frac{1}{\vert G\vert}\vert G\vert v = v$$ However, I do not understand why the statement holds for $v\in V\setminus V^{G}$ as well. Is this simply an error on the author's part or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error. Since $V^G$ is a subspace the $\frac{1}{|G|}$ coefficient is irrelevant and I'm going to ignore it (let me know if I should explain further why I can do this, but I think it should be easy to figure out).

Consider what happens when you act by a fixed element $g_0\in G$, we have

\begin{align*}\phi_{g_0}(\sum_{g\in G}\phi_g v)&=\sum_{g\in G}\phi_{g_0}(\phi_g v)\\
&= \sum_{g\in G}\phi_{g_0g}v\end{align*}

Now try to figure out why this is the same thing as $\sum_{g\in G}\phi_g v$. In other words, why is the set $\{g_0g\mid g\in G\}$ the same as the set $\{g\mid g\in G\}$?

Comment: Of course! That makes perfect sense now, thanks a million!